# How to change language of bootstrap datetimepicker (not datepicker)

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap latest version (4.2.1) along with jQuery latest version, I am using moment.js too along with jquery.datetimepicker

I have included a locale file for language but its not working at all.

I've tried almost every method to change datetimepicker English language to Chinese language.

```
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({locale:'zh-CN'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the official [doc](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), you can see that there is no zh-Cn.

You have 3 options if you want to use Chinese :

> - zh - Simplified Chinese (简体中文)
> - zh-TW - Traditional Chinese (繁體中文)
> - ch - Simplified Chinese

Also there is a function to use moment as your default formatter :

```
$.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code and this   [documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) is really helpful.

```
    $.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment');
    $('#start_time').datetimepicker({
     i18n:{
      zh:{
       months:[
        '一月','二月','三月','四月',
        '五月','六月','七月','八月',
        '九月','十月','十一月','十二月',
       ],
       dayOfWeek:[
        "七", "一", "二", "三", 
        "四", "五", "六",
       ]
      }
     },
     timepicker:true,
     minTime:0,
     minDate:0,
    });
    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('zh');
    $('#start_time').datetimepicker({locale:'zh'});
```